# Can MySQL split a column?

Tags: mysql, split

I have a column that has comma separated data:

```
1,2,3
3,2,1
4,5,6
5,5,5
```

I'm trying to run a search that would query each value of the CSV string individually.

```
0<first<5   and  1<second<3  and  2<third<4
```

I get that I could return all queries and split it myself and compare it myself. I'm curious if there is a way to do this so MySQL does that processing work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 53):

Use

```
substring_index(`column`,',',1) ==> first value
substring_index(substring_index(`column`,',',-2),',',1)=> second value
substring_index(substring_index(`column`,',',-1),',',1)=> third value
```

in your where clause.

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE 
substring_index(`column`,',',1)<0 
AND
substring_index(`column`,',',1)>5
```

Comment: I had to use substring_index(substring_index(`column`,',',-1),',',1) to get the second value.  Using -2 consistently gave me the first value.  Worked great, though.  :)

Comment: The indices in this answer get a bit confusing as you add more rows.

Comment: Great solution. Worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 35):

It seems to work:

```
substring_index ( substring_index ( context,',',1 ), ',', -1) 
substring_index ( substring_index ( context,',',2 ), ',', -1)
substring_index ( substring_index ( context,',',3 ), ',', -1)
substring_index ( substring_index ( context,',',4 ), ',', -1)
```

it means 1st value, 2nd, 3rd, etc.

#### Explanation:

The inner `substring_index` returns the first n values that are comma separated. So if your original string is "34,7,23,89", `substring_index( context,',', 3)` returns "34,7,23".
The outer `substring_index` takes the value returned by the inner `substring_index` and the `-1` allows you to take the last value. So you get "23" from the "34,7,23".
Instead of `-1` if you specify `-2`, you'll get "7,23", because it took the last two values.

#### Example:

```
select * from MyTable where substring_index(substring_index(prices,',',1),',',-1)=3382;
```

Here, `prices` is the name of a column in `MyTable`.

Comment: This is the clearer answer given it's indices are more structured.

Comment: best solution for the usecase

Answer (score 12):

Usually [substring_index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) does what you want:

```
mysql> select substring_index("foo@gmail.com","@",-1);
+-----------------------------------------+
| substring_index("foo@gmail.com","@",-1) |
+-----------------------------------------+
| gmail.com                               |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 4):

You may get what you want by using the MySQL REGEXP or LIKE.

See the [MySQL Docs on Pattern Matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/pattern-matching.html)

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to this, I've strings of the form:
Some words 303

where I'd like to split off the numerical part from the tail of the string.
This seems to point to a possible solution:

http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/222421

The problem however, is that you only get the answer "yes, it matches", and not the start index of the regexp match.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another variant I posted on related question. The `REGEX` check to see if you are out of bounds is useful, so for a table column you would put it in the where clause.

```
SET @Array = 'one,two,three,four';
SET @ArrayIndex = 2;
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN @Array REGEXP CONCAT('((,).*){',@ArrayIndex,'}') 
    THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@Array,',',@ArrayIndex+1),',',-1) 
    ELSE NULL
END AS Result;
```

- `SUBSTRING_INDEX(string, delim, n)` returns the first n
- `SUBSTRING_INDEX(string, delim, -1)` returns the last only
- `REGEXP '((delim).*){n}'` checks if there are n delimiters (i.e. you are in bounds)

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Oleksiy's answer, here is one that can work with strings of variable segment lengths (within reasonable limits), for example comma-separated addresses:

```
SELECT substring_index ( substring_index ( address,',',1 ), ',', -1) AS address_line_1,
   IF(address_parts > 1, substring_index ( substring_index ( address,',',2 ), ',', -1), '') AS address_line_2,
   IF(address_parts > 2, substring_index ( substring_index ( address,',',3 ), ',', -1), '') AS address_line_3,
   IF(address_parts > 3, substring_index ( substring_index ( address,',',4 ), ',', -1), '') AS address_line_4,
   IF(address_parts > 4, substring_index ( substring_index ( address,',',5 ), ',', -1), '') AS address_line_5
FROM (
    SELECT address, LENGTH(address) - LENGTH(REPLACE(address, ',', '')) AS address_parts
      FROM mytable
) AS addresses
```

Answer (score -2):

It's working..

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'1', 1), '2', 1), '3', 1), '4', 1), '5', 1), '6', 1)
, '7', 1), '8', 1), '9', 1), '0', 1) as new_col  
FROM table_name group by new_col;
```