# Mysql string split

Tags: mysql, split, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can Mysql Split a column ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096679/can-mysql-split-a-column)

I have one string column and one comma separated column as below

Example, 
I have the table,

```
Col1 | col2
1    | a,b,c
2    | d,e
```

From above, I want

```
Col1,Col2
1   ,a
1   ,b
1   ,c
2   ,d
2   ,e
```

How to achieve this

**It is not the Exact Duplicate.**

Comment: Are you sure that you want that comas ? ;)

Comment: Sorry, but I smell bad database design here. You should use a table that looks exactly like your second example (without the commas).

Comment: This column has been asked multiple times on stack overflow. See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096679/can-mysql-split-a-column

Comment: @hsz : No need of that commas

@ user589983: Could you please provide me the solution in simple way

Answer (score 23):

You can do this using a stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION strSplit(x VARCHAR(65000), delim VARCHAR(12), pos INTEGER) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(65000)
BEGIN
  DECLARE output VARCHAR(65000);
  SET output = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos)
                 , LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos - 1)) + 1)
                 , delim
                 , '');
  IF output = '' THEN SET output = null; END IF;
  RETURN output;
END $$


CREATE PROCEDURE BadTableToGoodTable()
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INTEGER;

  SET i = 1;
  REPEAT
    INSERT INTO GoodTable (col1, col2)
      SELECT col1, strSplit(col2, ',', i) FROM BadTable
      WHERE strSplit(col2, ',', i) IS NOT NULL;
    SET i = i + 1;
    UNTIL ROW_COUNT() = 0
  END REPEAT;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```