# sql query Split Color

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can Mysql Split a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096679/can-mysql-split-a-column)
>   [Mysql string split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152137/mysql-string-split)

I have this in a table:

```
id  color
1   red/green/blue/orange
2   blue
3   
4   red/green
```

I will a sql query maybe this :

```
color
red
green
blue
orange
blue
red
green
```

Comment: normalize your table, and this problem will go away automatically.

Comment: No, *please* don't do that. Every time you design a table like this a kitten somewhere dies. I recommend you read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 0):

What the commenters want to suggest, is splitting the values into separate rows:

```
id color
1  red
1  green
1  blue
1  orange
2  blue
3  NULL
4  red
4  green
```

Then you can easily select:

```
select color from color_table;
```

or every color only once:

```
select distinct color from color_table;
```

Comment: You're right, but suggesting a *full* normalization might be too much for the first step.