# How to split string with date as delimiter?

Tags: php, mysql

Could you help me with splitting large string into substrings?

Scenario:
In one of fields inside MySQL table I've got string in which there is an activity log in following format:

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss - Name1 Surname1 - Activity1
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss - Name2 Surname2 - Activity2
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss - Name3 Surname3 - Multiline Activity1
Multiline Activity2
Multiline Activity3
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss - Name4 Surname4 - Activity4
```

Question:

How can I split the above data into array like this:

```
id       date                    name                    activity
1        yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss     Name1 Surname1          Activity1
2        yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss     Name2 Surname2          Activity2
3        yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss     Name3 Surname3          Multiline Activity 1, Multiline Activity2, Multiline Activity 3
4        yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss     Name4 Surname4          Activity4
```

using PHP or MySQL query?

I know it could be done somehow, but unfortunately by knowledge of PHP/MySQL doesn't allow me to parse text with variable delimiter (date), or maybe there is another way?

Comment: Why don't you just split on the '-'?

Comment: You can do it even with mysql. Check this great answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152137/mysql-string-split However, this is advanced usage, for master programmers :)

Comment: i think your table design is wrong .you can use explode function in php to get the output as desired

Comment: Unfortunately I'm working on existing database, so I'm not the designer of the data structure. That's question is related to future conversion of the datastructure into more accessible format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with **[preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)**:

```
$string = <<<STR
2013-06-04 12:12:12 - Name1 Surname1 - Activity1
2013-06-04 12:12:12 - Name2 Surname2 - Activity2
2013-06-04 12:12:12 - Name3 Surname3 - Multiline Activity1
Multiline Activity2
Multiline Activity3
2013-06-04 12:12:12 - Name4 Surname4 - Activity4
STR;

$arr = preg_split("/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) - (.*) - (.*)[\r\n]?/", $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

$arr = array_filter($arr);

print_r($arr);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2013-06-04 12:12:12
    [2] => Name1 Surname1
    [3] => Activity1
    [5] => 2013-06-04 12:12:12
    [6] => Name2 Surname2
    [7] => Activity2
    [9] => 2013-06-04 12:12:12
    [10] => Name3 Surname3
    [11] => Multiline Activity1
    [12] => Multiline Activity2
Multiline Activity3

    [13] => 2013-06-04 12:12:12
    [14] => Name4 Surname4
    [15] => Activity4
)
```

**Example for a real usage:**

```
$i = -1; 
$result = array();

foreach($arr as $value) {
    if(preg_match("/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/", $value)) {
        // 1st element - datetime
        $i++;
        $result[$i]['datetime'] = $value;
    } elseif(!isset($result[$i]['name'])) {
        // 2nd element - name
        $result[$i]['name'] = $value;
    } else {
        // 3rd element - activities separated by comma
        if(!isset($result[$i]['activities'])) {
            $result[$i]['activities'] = $value;
        } else {
            $result[$i]['activities'] .= ', ' . $value;        
        }
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [datetime] => 2013-06-04 12:12:12
            [name] => Name1 Surname1
            [activities] => Activity1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [datetime] => 2013-06-04 12:12:12
            [name] => Name2 Surname2
            [activities] => Activity2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [datetime] => 2013-06-04 12:12:12
            [name] => Name3 Surname3
            [activities] => Multiline Activity1
, Multiline Activity2
Multiline Activity3

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [datetime] => 2013-06-04 12:12:12
            [name] => Name4 Surname4
            [activities] => Activity4
        )

)
```

Comment: thanks, it's exactly what I've been looking for! cheers, and have a good day sir ;)

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the MySQL result and for each row, perform this:

```
$row = explode(' - ', $row);
```

Comment: Problems with this solution: A name may be hyphenated e.g. John - Doe.  Activity contains some unknown set of characters (to us).

Comment: @BLaZuRE And how do you know that?

Comment: I code for worst-case scenarios, so I point out potential problems instead of downvoting.

Comment: thanks, but @BLaZuRE got that point... Activity is usually multi line text with every character (and their combinations) possible