# Use of FInd_IN_SET vs IN clause MYSQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-optimization, sqlperformance

I have a stored procedure that is similar to below

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
WHERE Tag IN (ids)
```

here `Tag` is an `Integer` column.

I tired to pass in comma separated values as string into the stored procedure but it does not work. Then I used stored procedure like below

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(Tag, ids)
```

This works very well, the only problem is my table is very big - millions of rows and using FIND_IN_SET takes too long compared to IN when running a direct SQL statement.

What would be the best performance optimized option to use?

Is there a split function that can convert the ids into integer and parse it ready for IN clause? I think that would be the best option. Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152137/mysql-string-split

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prepare a statement and then execute it:

```
set @sql = concat('select * from table1 where tag in (', ids, ')');

PREPARE q FROM @sql;

execute q;
```

This constructs the string for each execution, so you can use `in`.  The resulting execute should be able to use an index on `tag`, which should speed things up considerably.

Comment: that actually works
in one test 
Find_in_Set :3.978sec 94rows return
IN :1.732sec 94rows return
concat(yourexample): 1.747 sec 94 rows