# using php to do this type of job

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have this type of links in my database and its in millions

```
http://fo.website1.com/image/2584372/600full-name.jpg
```

i want to convert this link to this link

```
http://website2.com/pic/25/84/37/2/600full-name.jpg
```

i know with one line of sql replace i can achieve first part.i.e upto this part i dont have any issue http://fo.website1.com/image/ it can be easily done with

```
UPDATE tableA set link= replace(link, "http://fo.website1.com/image/", "http://website2.com/pic/")
```

but i am more concerned about next part how to achieve that

that number ranges from 1 to 10000000 and for every number i have created subfolders after every 2 digit/

for example  343433 will go in 34/34/33 like that 6456454  will be 64/56/45/4

any idea how can i achieve this

i have divided like this

```
  $c1=explode("/",$websitelink,-1);  $city1=end($c1);

  $f1=substr($city1, 0, 2);

  $f2=substr($city1, 2, 2);  

  $f3=substr($city1, 4, 2);

  $f4=substr($city1, 6, 10);
```

want to replace website1 numbers with the desired numbers as given above and dont want to touch others

```
   Kurbaan HD Movie Wallpaper #1 way2enjoyKurbaan 1024x768 Wallpaper # 1Wallpapers[img]http://iv1.website1.com/image/6661434/600full-justin-timberlake.jpg[/img][img]http://media1.santabanta.com/full1/Bollywood%20Movies/All%20the%20Best/all-the-best-0a.jpg[/img][img]http://media1.santabanta.com/full1/Bollywood%20Movies/Do%20Knot%20Disturb/do-knot-disturb-0a.jpg[/img][img]http://media1.santabanta.com/full1/Bollywood%20Movies/London%20Dreams/london-dreams-8e.jpg[/img][img]http://iv1.website1.com/image/1661434/600full-justin-timberlake.jpg[/img][img]http://media1.santabanta.com/full1/Global%20Celebrities(F)/Hope%20Dworaczyk/hope-dworaczyk-7a.jpg[/img]
```

Comment: Writing code would be a good start. Go try and come here if you face a probem with that code.

Comment: @Bartdude sorry i should mention some codes pz see my question again

Comment: your substr() approach is good - don't know if it is the most efficient way, but it will do its job

Comment: @Priya Why is the example you have given not working?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the number (Using your code):

```
$c1=explode("/",$websitelink,-1);
$city1=end($c1);
```

Try using [`str_split()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) instead and then [`join()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) to create the new path:

```
$output = str_split($city1, 2);
$path = join('/', $output);
```

This will return `34/34/33` for 343433, and `64/56/45/4` for 6456454.

Comment: i have this entry in database and from this entry i have to replace the numbers see the revised question last pararaph

Comment: To perform the string manipulations that those two lines of php with MySQL do you will probably need to use a stored procedure, take a look at these questions: [MySQL String Split](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152137/mysql-string-split) or [Can MySQL Split a Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096679/can-mysql-split-a-column)