# How to explode mysql field value and use it in SELECT query

Tags: mysql

How can i explode field value of table in select query ?

for e.g. i have 1 field in table named "coordinates" which contains latitude , longitude.

Now i want to use this latitude and longitude in select query.

Can i separate this values and use it in select query ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096679/can-mysql-split-a-column

Comment: BTW, as far as I understand, that's violation of 1NF (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)

Comment: @Kel: +1, you're absolutely correct!

Comment: the database schema should have contained 2 fields - 1 for latitude & 1 for longitude

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-a-spatially-enabled-mysql-database.html have a look there.  @kel, i still think you can see a point (x,y or lat, long) as one field. Not necessarily breaking the Codd's rules?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the comments are correct: this is a violation of normal form. Always store separate data in separate columns - it will make your life easier.

If you try to write a select statement that parses the `coordinates` field and tries to filter on one or both halves, you will have a query that runs SUPER slowly, since an index on that column will not function. Instead, I would recommend writing a query to split that column into two, such as the following:

```
alter table `your_table`
    add column `coordinate_x` int null;
alter table `your_table`
    add column `coordinate_y` int null;
update `your_table`
    set `coordinate_x` = substring(`coordinates`,1,locate(',',`coordinates`))
        ,`coordinate_y`= substring(`coordinates`,locate(',',`coordinates`)+1);
alter table `your_table`
    drop column `coordinates`;
alter table `your_table`
    modify column `coordinate_x` int not null;
alter table `your_table`
    modify column `coordinate_y` int not null;
```

You could then index `coordinate_x` and `coordinate_y` to make your select statement run quickly.