# split string in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

i have field that has records like '1:23,2:23' and '2:43'

is there any way to split string into 1,23,2,23 (separate values, so i can work with them independently) 
 using mysql query.
for example add them to another table like

```
 row1:   1 | 23
 row2:   2 | 43
```

the string can contain more pairs of keys/ values

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096679/can-mysql-split-a-column

Comment: the main problem is i don't know exactly how many pairs is in the field. it can be like '1:jigtrg,2:ew,3:wer' etc

Comment: How about writing stored procedures?

Answer (score 0):

Check out regular expression matching

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Just replace ':' with ','.

Answer (score 0):

I may misunderstand your question but here are my thoughts...

SQL is meant to fetch data, not parse it. Parsing should happen on the application side. If you need to create a list for something like an IN clause then you probably need to reconsider you data-model to allow the values you would normally parse out to be in separate rows.

I am not saying you can't do some string magic in SQL but it's usually a sign of a design issue.