# mysql split string

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can Mysql Split a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096679/can-mysql-split-a-column)

I have a single row with 1 column in mysql that has data in the form of 'Dave=>Anderson, Mick=>Jagger, Foxxy=>Brown'. Is there a way in mysql to split the string & iterate through each split & then subsequently format the data?

I have the following:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(  `names` ,  ',', 1 ) AS mynames FROM  `table`
```

This will obviously give me just 'Dave=>Anderson' and not the rest of the names.

(I realize I can do this in PHP but wanted to know if this can be done in mysql)

UPDATE: 
I should be clearer: I would like to return a separate row for each of the names:

```
    +-----------------+
    | mynames         |
    +-----------------+
    | Dave Anderson   |
    +-----------------+
    | Mick Jagger     |
    +-----------------+
    | Foxxy Brown     |
    +-----------------+
```

Comment: In that case, you shouldn't store the entries like that in a single field. Split them off into their own 1-to-many table and they'd automatically be on seperate rows.

Comment: i'd rather not do that...in my case it creates a couple hundred thousand tables, which makes my db hard to maintain

Comment: 100K+ tables - you mean rows right ?

Comment: Sounds like not having separate rows is making your DB hard to maintain. Having another table with a row for each name is how relational databases are designed to work.