# MySQL query finding values in a comma separated string

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I have a field `COLORS (varchar(50))` in a my table `SHIRTS` that contains a comma delimited string such as `1,2,5,12,15,`. Each number representing the available colors.

When running the query `select * from shirts where colors like '%1%'` to get all the red shirts (color=1), I also get the shirts whose color is grey (=12) and orange (=15).

How should I rewrite the query so that is selects ONLY the color 1 and not all colors containing the number 1?

Comment: You could do this via regex, I suppose, but the much better solution would be to break shirt colors into a separate table (colors) and use a join table (shirt_colors) using the ids of color/shirt to link them.

Comment: I can't believe with 6 answers *none* of them mentioned MySQL's SET data type..

Comment: check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559876/finding-exact-value-from-a-comma-separated-string-in-php-mysql

Answer (score 218, accepted):

The classic way would be to add commas to the left and right:

```
select * from shirts where CONCAT(',', colors, ',') like '%,1,%'
```

But [find_in_set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) also works:

```
select * from shirts where find_in_set('1',colors) <> 0
```

Comment: I tried find_in_set but it returns the same result no matter the color value I enter... Any suggestions?

Comment: @bikey77: Maybe this is the problem, the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) says: This function does not work properly if the first argument contains a comma (“,”) character.

Comment: My wrong, it was a logical mistake due to the same dummy values. It works fine. Thanks!

Comment: @Andomar Before i found your answer i wast struggling with IN but yours is work like a charm... Thank you so much..

Comment: It has a performance impact as Find_in_set doesn't used index

Comment: @KamranShahid would it be possible to index the field fulltext to alleviate the performance hit?

Comment: Is this method better than REGEXP? WHERE color REGEXP "(^|,)1(,|$)"?

Answer (score 39):

[FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) is your friend in this case

```
select * from shirts where FIND_IN_SET(1,colors)
```

Comment: find_in_set is too slow for large tables

Answer (score 30):

Take a look at the [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function for MySQL.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM shirts 
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1',colors) > 0
```

Comment: Beware: find in set doesn't uses indexes on table.

Answer (score 12):

This will work for sure, and I actually tried it out:

```
lwdba@localhost (DB test) :: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS shirts;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

lwdba@localhost (DB test) :: CREATE TABLE shirts
    -> (<BR>
    -> id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    -> ticketnumber INT,
    -> colors VARCHAR(30)
    -> );<BR>
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.19 sec)

lwdba@localhost (DB test) :: INSERT INTO shirts (ticketnumber,colors) VALUES
    -> (32423,'1,2,5,12,15'),
    -> (32424,'1,5,12,15,30'),
    -> (32425,'2,5,11,15,28'),
    -> (32426,'1,2,7,12,15'),
    -> (32427,'2,4,8,12,15');
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

lwdba@localhost (DB test) :: SELECT * FROM shirts WHERE LOCATE(CONCAT(',', 1 ,','),CONCAT(',',colors,',')) > 0;
+----+--------------+--------------+
| id | ticketnumber | colors       |
+----+--------------+--------------+
|  1 |        32423 | 1,2,5,12,15  |
|  2 |        32424 | 1,5,12,15,30 |
|  4 |        32426 | 1,2,7,12,15  |
+----+--------------+--------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Hey @rolandomysqldba, I test your query and it works ok but I need to make some changes in it. Let's say if I want to get all the shirts where color value is 1,2 in the column.

Answer (score 7):

If the set of colors is more or less fixed, the most efficient and also most readable way would be to use string constants in your app and then use MySQL's `SET` type with `FIND_IN_SET('red',colors)` in your queries. When using the `SET` type with [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), MySQL uses one integer to store all values and uses binary `"and"` operation to check for presence of values which is way more efficient than scanning a comma-separated string.

In `SET('red','blue','green')`, `'red'` would be stored internally as `1`, `'blue'` would be stored internally as `2` and `'green'` would be stored internally as `4`. The value `'red,blue'` would be stored as `3` (`1|2`) and `'red,green'` as `5` (`1|4`).

Answer (score 4):

```
select * from shirts where find_in_set('1',colors) <> 0
```

Works for me

Answer (score 3):

If you're using MySQL, there is a method REGEXP that you can use...

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

So then you would use:

```
SELECT * FROM `shirts` WHERE `colors` REGEXP '\b1\b'
```

Comment: Couldn't figure this one out, although I'm pretty sure it's my fault. Thanks a mil mate.

Answer (score 3):

You should actually fix your database schema so that you have three tables:

```
shirt: shirt_id, shirt_name
color: color_id, color_name
shirtcolor: shirt_id, color_id
```

Then if you want to find all of the shirts that are red, you'd do a query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM shirt, color
WHERE color.color_name = 'red'
  AND shirt.shirt_id = shirtcolor.shirt_id
  AND color.color_id = shirtcolor.color_id
```

Comment: @Blindy: That's only true if you assume the OP has edit rights on the database schema; has the time to redesign the database, migrate the data, and refactor all clients; and that the reduction of complexity for this query outweighs the increase in complexity in the rest of the application.

Comment: @Andomar, then again when he'll run into size restrictions for row retrievals and his "records" will get clipped, THAT's when the real fun will begin!

Comment: @Blindy: You're missing the point; I'm not arguing that he has the best solution, just that not everyone has the freedom to redesign his environment to his liking

Comment: I agree with @Andomar

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by following function.

Run following query to create function.

```
DELIMITER ||
CREATE FUNCTION `TOTAL_OCCURANCE`(`commastring` TEXT, `findme`     VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS int(11)
NO SQL
-- SANI: First param is for comma separated string and 2nd for string to find.
return ROUND (   
    (
        LENGTH(commastring)
        - LENGTH( REPLACE ( commastring, findme, "") ) 
    ) / LENGTH(findme)        
);
```

And call this function like this

```
msyql> select TOTAL_OCCURANCE('A,B,C,A,D,X,B,AB', 'A');
```

Comment: if it is counting properly, you should never need to use `ROUND`... if it doesn't return a whole number then there's some other issue

Answer (score 0):

**1. For MySQL:**

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET(5, columnname) AS result 
FROM table
```

**2.For Postgres SQL :**

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLENAME f
WHERE 'searchvalue' = ANY (string_to_array(COLUMNNAME, ','))
```

**Example**

```
select * 
from customer f
where '11' = ANY (string_to_array(customerids, ','))
```

Answer (score -11):

All the answers are not really correct, try this:

```
select * from shirts where 1 IN (colors);
```