# Count Delimited value in Column

Tags: mysql, csv

Please suggest me an SQL Query for the Below
I have Ids of Items Stored in one column like this 1,2,3,4 as Delimited or CSV value.
Now i want count no of items in one particular row in one particular cell.

i.e 
If i have 25,45,26,45,46 in a cell in table.
I want the output like 5 which is nothing but the number of items in a row in a cell say (0,0).
Thank you so much for your Replies

Comment: A properly normalized database would make this unecessary

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020001/how-to-count-items-in-comma-seperated-list-mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count items in comma separated list MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020001/how-to-count-items-in-comma-separated-list-mysql)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you don't have values like '123,123,' (note the comma at the end) this should work:

```
SELECT
LENGTH(yourColumn) - LENGTH(REPLACE(yourColumn, ',', '')) + 1 AS numberOfItemsInRow
FROM yourTable;
```

Find more information [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html).

**But it would really be better to normalize your database!**

Comment: Thank you so much Stack Overflow Rocks

Comment: @user1093513 I'd appreciate it if you would thank me by accepting my answer (click the check mark to the left of my answer). Thanks.

Comment: @we.mamat +1 for +1 :) Did you mean the answer or the comment with being cheeky? The zero to the left of my answer doesn't reflect that. ;)

Comment: very well, +1 on the anwser as well! :D

Comment: [hive query] REPLACE -> REGEXP_REPLACE!