# is there anyway to count values in a set of mysql cloumn

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I get the number of values specified in a [MySQL `SET` column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set.html)?

[image: list of values shown separated with commas]

Is there any built function in mysql ?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE SomeCondition` ?

Comment: I have no glue what that picture shows. What do you mean with "SET"?

Comment: I think he means the number of comma-separated elements in the string.

Comment: @Barmar yes extracly.Sorry for the bad english.if you can please edit the question ?

Comment: Except it's a `SET` datatype, not `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`.

Comment: @Barmar However how to get the count of it?

Comment: it's a text datatype.

Comment: @ajacian81 Why do you say that? The question says it's a SET. SET is displayed as a comma-separated list, but it's stored internally as bits.

Comment: @samitha: Your question asks for guessing around. It's not actually clear what the image technically represents. We do not see a table defintion here. There is no SQL query related to the image etc.. And then I've found this already in the Mysql manual: *"To determine all possible values for a `SET` column, use `SHOW COLUMNS FROM tbl_name LIKE set_col` and parse the `SET` definition in the `Type` column of the output."* - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set.html - it should be part of a well written answer if you're actually asking about `SET`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to count items in comma seperated list MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020001/how-to-count-items-in-comma-seperated-list-mysql)

Comment: @Barmar it's a set in that it's a comma seperated list, but if you look at the picture, it's defined as a `text` field.

Comment: @ajacian81 Where do you see the table schema in the picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id, LENGTH(colname) - LENGTH(REPLACE(colname, ',', '')) + 1 AS set_count
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10738323/1176436

Assuming you don't have values like '123,123,' (note the comma at the end) this should work:

```
SELECT
LENGTH(yourColumn) - LENGTH(REPLACE(yourColumn, ',', '')) + 1 AS numberOfItemsInRow
FROM yourTable;
```

Find more information here.

But it would really be better to normalize your database!

Comment: Why do you think currently it's not normalized? It would be especially good if you point what particular 3NF requirement is violated. Thank you.

Comment: I copied and pasted from the answer provided, however, you  have a column with multiple values - you can join another table instead with a many to one relationship.

Comment: are you sure you understand the aim of a `SET` type?

Comment: @zerkms it's not a set, it's a text field with a bunch of comma separated values.

Comment: it's weird because an OP stated it is a `SET` and even provided a link to the corresponding type in documentation