# How to count id numbers separated by a comma from one cell

Tags: mysql

I have table with 5 columns and one of it is column called product_id where i store id's spearated by a comma like:

1,23,43

is that possible to count that numbers by mysql query? I need to know it to make pagination of products...

i need to know that there is 3 ids (3 products)

best regards
m.

Comment: here's a good article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020001/how-to-count-items-in-comma-seperated-list-mysql

Comment: Did you write this schema, or do you have any influence over its design? You shouldn't be storing [many-to-many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model) relationships like that.

Comment: i have products stored in DB normal as one product one row BUT there is smth like promotion and I put these products to that promotion ... connect these products with promotion table, row and put id's to one cell with comma separated. So i need to know how many products is on this promotion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
select LENGTH(product_id) - LENGTH(REPLACE(product_id, ',', ''))+1 as counts
from table1
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6d87/1)

Comment: Thank You, that works :) i made count in other way too, but nice to learn from You :) best regards

Comment: you welcome newbie :) !