# MySQL query grouping by date and retrieving varchar value on row

Tags: php, mysql

It's highly likely this has been answered elsewhere, I can't find anything so if you can link to another post that would be ace.

I have a MySQL table which lists tickets and payments, amongst other columns. I didn't design table and I can't change too much; adding a column is out of the question. Here's a simplified version of the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE cases (
    id INT PRIMARY, 
    created TIMESTAMP, -- when created in db- each day the table is truncated and a new csv imported
    opened DATE, -- will differ from the timestamp, this is the column I want to group by
    total DECIMAL, -- not relevant in this question but i'm totaling this by month too
    tickets VARCHAR(256) -- the one I want to count, two tickets would look like '"foo1234","baa5678"', there is no pattern (i.e. Same prefix) in the tickets either
);
```

The `tickets` column references possibly multiple tickets. Each is wrapped in double quotes in the DB (I have a feeling this is a bit insecure, not my decision and I can't really change it), with each reference separated by a comma (if there is more than one).

There are other columns like client name and date closed, but they are irrelevant in this case

I've written a query which will group the rows by month, year and total the payments for each month.
I want the results to also include the count of tickets, itemized monthly. It can be assumed that there will always be at least one ticket. On the front end I either count the commas and add one, or explode by comma and count the array which works fine for a hand full of rows (there are rarely more than 4 tickets in one row), but as this will form a report of the entire database I want it to be a bit more efficient.

I don't have any code to post (I'm not looking for someone to write it for me, just point me in the right direction, maybe there is a method i'm forgetting?), as I'm not really sure where to start with it, all other posts similar to this are about grouping and totaling numbers (which I also need to do but i'm ok with that part), but nothing on how to do it with a string. `SUM()`, but with a string.

Comment: Pls show us an example of your tables (doesn't need to be true data) but we need at least the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily solved by using `CONCAT_WS`, read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html)

`CONCAT_WS` will concatenate the strings with a seperator chosen by you, in your case you would do that with a comma: `CONCAT_WS(',',string_column)`

This wil give you a all the strings separated by commas. if you really need the count than you can continue with this: [How to count items in comma separated list MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020001/how-to-count-items-in-comma-separated-list-mysql)

Using this would give:

```
LENGTH(CONCAT_WS(',',string_column)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT_WS(',',string_column), ',', ''))+1
```

+1 because you need have one more result than you have comma's

Comment: YES! Thank you, thats exactly what i was after. I'm little annoyed with myself since i already tried CONCAT.'But hey ho!

Comment: :) no problem, happy to help!