# Variable as list doesn't work - manual list does

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL query finding values in a comma separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033047/mysql-query-finding-values-in-a-comma-separated-string)

I have a strange problem, that I hope you guys can answer for me.
If i use g.questions (which is a commaseperated varchar list), this only outputs the first id.
But if I manually types in "1,2,3,4" instead of g.questions, I get what I expect...

What's going on? :-)

```
SELECT q.id FROM `questions` q 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `game` g 
ON g.id = 1 
WHERE q.id IN (g.questions)
```

Comment: You cannot do it that way.  `g.questions` is a single string from MySQL's point of view and cannot be substituted for an `IN()`.  MySQL sees it as `WHERE q.id IN ('1,2,3,4')`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski But why does it return the first id then? The first id is not equal to the concatenated string

Comment: How are you constructing the g.questions varchar list? Is it queried from a table in some manner?

Comment: @ChetterHummin hard to say without seeing the data perhaps because of the left join on `g.id =1`

Comment: @ChetterHummin If you are in a position to change this schema, I strongly recommend fixing this so the column is normalized out into another table rather than stored as a list. It will cause increasing headaches and always be basically immune to good indexing.

Comment: Would you create tables for each of those cells? That would mean thousands of tables...?

Comment: No, a table with 2 columns which are foreign keys to `q.id` and `g.question_id` (or whatever that column is called). For each `q.id`, you would have multiple rows in the table which link it to a question id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
SELECT q.id FROM `questions` q 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `game` g 
ON g.id = 1 
WHERE concat(',',g.questions,',') like concat('%,',q.id,',%')
```

Adds a comma before and after your comma separated string to make sure each value is bound by  commas then uses like to match ",1,2,3,4," with "%,2,%" or whatever your q.id is.