# How to count how many times a string appears in a field in mySQL separated by comma?

Tags: php, mysql

My mySQL  is like this, an `id`, and a `texts` that have may phrases and some identical as below:

```
id      texts
2       abc,fd4g,oigdu,abc,abc
3       ccc,fff,fff,ccc,iop
```

My question is how can I show using PHP/mySQL

1. per id

`2 - abc - 3 times`

`2 - fd4g - 1 times`

`2 - oigdu - 1 times`

`3 - ccc - 2 times`

`3 - fff - 2 times`

`3 -iop - 1 times`

2. or searching via the text

   `abc - 2 times - 2`

   `fd4g - 1 times - 2`

   `oigdu - 1 times - 2`

   `ccc - 2 times - 3`

   `fff - 2 times - 3`

   `iop - 1 times - 3`

-

If my mySQL structure was :

```
id      texts
2       abc
2      fd4g
2      oigdu
2      abc
2      abc
3       ccc
3      fff
3      fff
3      ccc
3      iop
```

would this be easier?

Comment: Any attempts so far?

Comment: your suggested structure should be easier to handle. with your suggested structure one could do `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table GROUP BY texts`

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos Infinitely.

Comment: You cannot accomplish what you want directly using SQL (it is not built for that). You will need to bring the lines in from SQL and perform the string counting in code

Comment: This thread has also been answered over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033047/mysql-query-finding-values-in-a-comma-separated-string/47069224#47069224)

Answer (score 3):

The second structure would be easier. But you shouldn't name your first column `id` because the `id`-field usually has `unique key` values, that means only auto-incrementing values. You have multiple times the same number, so you it's obviously not unique but something different.

With the other query you could run

```
SELECT id, texts, COUNT(*) FROM tbl group by id, texts
```

and your result would be

```
2  |  abc  |  3
2  | fd4g  |  1
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the the count of same value by doing this code

`select id, texts, count(id) from table group by texts`