# matching comma seperated value from a string in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table job_registration having following structure

```
id     name    email     keyskills
1      A       a@a.in    JAVA,SQLSERVER
2      B       b@b.in    JAVA,PHP,MYSQL,SQLSERVER
3      C       c@c.in    MYSQL,SQLSERVER
```

I want to fetch email of people who has the keyskills like SQLSERVER. please suggest

Thanks in Advance

Comment: duplicate of: [5033047/mysql-query-finding-values-in-a-comma-separated-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033047/mysql-query-finding-values-in-a-comma-separated-string)

Comment: Don't store multiple values in a single column. Fix your database design and your problems go away.

Comment: What should be best table structure for this scenario.. is this like one to many relationship

Answer (score 1):

Use FIND_IN_SET

```
select email
from job_registration 
where find_in_set(keyskills, 'SQLSERVER') > 0
and find_in_set(keyskills, 'JAVA') > 0
```

But actually you are better of by changing your table structure and store only single values in a column. A better table design would be using 3 tables

```
job_registration table
----------------------
id     
name    
email


skills table
------------
id
name


user_skills table
-----------------
user_id
skill_id
```

Comment: yes actually find_in_set will work only for single value like if i want to get the email of people having keyskills java then find_in_set would not work. Any suggestion for multiple options.

Comment: @salloy: the suggestion for multiple values is in the answer: "*change your table structure*"

Comment: @salloy: For multiple values you can use it multiple times. Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use REGEXP to match with text in a column

```
SELECT email
FROM job_registration
WHERE keyskills REGEXP 'SQLSERVER'
```

Comment: That would also find entries that contain `YOURSQLSERVER` or `SQLSERVERMIGRATION` (a problem that originally stems from the wrong database design)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: that is true, we could use FIND_IN_SET but there is already a solution with that and moreover it is also not a full proof solution