# MySQL WHERE IN Returns only 1 record

Tags: php, mysql

I' am storing the profile friends ID in a string format comma delimited. When the run the Query, its gives 1 record whereas it should return with 2 records.

MySQL Query

```
SELECT * FROM PROFILES WHERE profile_id IN(SELECT profile_friends FROM PROFILES WHERE profile_id = '1')
```

Which gives this result (The results should be 2 records NOT 1 Record)
[image]

When I run the following Query, gives me two ID's that are in a profile_friends field.

```
SELECT profile_friends FROM PROFILES WHERE profile_id = '1'
```

[image]

Comment: Your query becomes `WHERE profile_id IN('5,10')`. MySQL apparently tries to parse that as int, resulting in `WHERE profile_id IN(5)`. The real fun starts with `5,9` I suppose, depending on your locale that might become `6`. Don't use comma-separated fields for joins. If you really must, see [MySQL query finding values in a comma separated string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033047/mysql-query-finding-values-in-a-comma-separated-string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use following Query

```
SELECT * FROM PROFILES WHERE FIND_IN_SET(profile_id,(SELECT profile_friends FROM PROFILES WHERE profile_id = '1'))
```

**IN** clause only use when you search value from integer field

But your field(profile_friends) is string so following clause you need to use.

> FIND_IN_SET