# how to use where condition from stored data in array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, where-in

```
id | name | permission
1  | John | 1,4,3
2  | mike | 7,4,3
3  | sky  | 3,2,1
```

this is my database

now i have fetch select query with where condition

e.g.  **select  * from `friend` where permission='4'**

but i m not able fetch any data so what to do ?

Please help

Comment: Don't store the permission values like that, it will only cause you a lot of problems. Have one row for each permission! And, also, use correct data types, integer in this case!

Comment: find_in_set or something like that for mysql query.

Comment: Normalization is for this purpose! store different permissions in different rows

Comment: anyways is the permission tab a list or normal string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select * from friend where FIND_IN_SET('4',permission);

Comment: Accept it as answer if you finding its working for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have multiple permissions stored together in a string.

To you, the query looks like:

```
select * from friend where permission='4'
```

That means anything containing 4.
To mysql, it sees:

```
select * from friend where permission= ONLY '4'
// Meaning the permissions column can ONLY CONTAIN 4.
// Also, ONLY is meant as a visual, don't use it in queries.
```

Try:

```
find_in_set('4',permission) <> 0
// This means It needs to find number 4 and can't return 0 results.
```

Check out these for more info:

[MySQL query finding values in a comma separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033047/mysql-query-finding-values-in-a-comma-separated-string)

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by the following query :

```
select * from friend where permission like '%4%'
```

Comment: This is a bad example as it will allow anything with 4. So if for some reason there was a permission 4 and 14, it would allow both, even if they only wanted just 4. This is because it just finds something with 4 in it from the way you wrote it.