# Need search a value from database from comma separated string

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, database

I have a table in database that is TEXT field. In this table i have stored my product ids . Now when i go to cart and get all product id of cart i want to match from database field and get only those ids that there stored in product id.

Please see image first.

[image]

In this field you will see "check_values" field. here all product ids are stored in comma separated.

Let me take a example

Like i have purchase a product that product id is 161. So i want to match 161 id from "check_value" filed and get only those ids (from images) that having 161.(11,14,15).

Hope you understand my question.

Comment: you can use `IN()` for this.

Comment: yes but all values are stored in comma separated

Comment: you can just implode then.

Comment: No, i want to match 161 from this table field (image) and get only those Ids that having 161.

Comment: Do not go forward with this design.  Create another table with one id and one check_values per row.

Comment: 161 comes from other page. i just want to match from image table

Comment: Take a look at this thread for why you shouldn't store your data this way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: LIKE operator is just for you. It is not optimal and etc, but it will just work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL query finding values in a comma separated string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033047/mysql-query-finding-values-in-a-comma-separated-string)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) e.g.

`SELECT * FROM images WHERE FIND_IN_SET(161, check_values) > 0`

Comment: that was my next thought ;-)

Comment: I had totally forgotten about that function.