# How to query comma separated string?

Tags: php, mysql

**Table_a**

```
column name: list_id
record 1: 1,2,5,6,8
record 2: 1,3,2
record 3: 6,7,2
record 4: 9,8,0
```

**Table_b**

```
id ='2';
```

How to select records that have `id='2'` in the comma separated string? From the above example it should return record 1,2 and 3.

Query(How to amend this query, please?):

```
SELECT * FROM Table_a,Table_b WHERE Table_b.id = Table_a.list_id;
```

Comment: Normalise your data. Problem solved.

Comment: @Dagon, thats the problem, I'm modifying existing system which has loads of data which is impossible to normalise now.

Comment: `Where Table_a.list_id like '%' + Table_b.id+ '%'`

Comment: @printxdiv0 This is not mysql syntax

Comment: @Keren see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033047/mysql-query-finding-values-in-a-comma-separated-string)

Comment: @sagi . Yeah, could be. I just wanted to point out the `Like` operator and wildcards.

Comment: " impossible to normalise " if I had a nickel...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use find_in_set function, but it is not optimized way you should normalize your data.

```
SELECT * FROM 
Table_a AS a 
JOIN Table_b AS b ON FIND_IN_SET(b.id,a.list_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
SELECT * FROM Table_a,Table_b WHERE Table_b.id = Table_a.list_id and 
concat(',',Table_a.list_id,',') like '%,2,%'
```

Comment: Why @sagi. Please share the reason so I can edit here

Comment: bcaz the last number of list_id dont have comma

Comment: In my query concat(',',Table_a.list_id,',') I have attached comma at both the ends.

Comment: And because the where clause will be false id <> list_id