# How to SELECT values if id available in column(Comma separated values) using mysql?

Tags: mysql

How to SELECT values if id available in column(Comma separated values) using MySQL?

Here I need to get all values when the given id=17 available in `group_id` column.

Table:

```
+------------+---------------+
| user_id    | group_id      |
+------------+---------------+
|          1 |         1,2,3 |
|          3 |      12,23,17 |
|          5 |         17,26 |   
+------------+---------------+
```

I try:

```
SELECT * FROM `group` WHERE units_id IN('17'); //No result
```

Expecting result:

```
+------------+---------------+
| user_id    | group_id      |
+------------+---------------+
|          3 |      12,23,17 |
|          5 |         17,26 |   
+------------+---------------+
```

Comment: It is very bad db design if you store values as csv

Comment: Please ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033047/mysql-query-finding-values-in-a-comma-separated-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.
You can use  [find_in_set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)  :

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE find_in_set('17',group_id) ORDER BY user_id;
```

RESULT:

```
+------------+---------------+
| user_id    | group_id      |
+------------+---------------+
|          3 |      12,23,17 |
|          5 |         17,26 |   
+------------+---------------+
```

REF: [MySQL query finding values in a comma separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033047/mysql-query-finding-values-in-a-comma-separated-string)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET`

```
SELECT * FROM `group` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(17,group_id);
```

**Note:** It's highly discouraged to store comma separated values in column. A must read:

[**Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

<sub>Yes</sub>

Also you shouldn't use `MySQL reserved words` as your identifer's name. Be careful to enclose by backtick while using.

Comment: Thanks. Your Query Worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ´find_in_set`

```
SELECT * FROM `group` WHERE find_in_set('17',units_id );
```

`IN` checks if a column contains values from a comma separated list

It is very bad db design if you store values as csv.

For more infoemartion see [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)