# Take one of the data from the table that has a comma

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a database with the first table, wherein the table comprises 3 fields like the example below, but I do not understand how to create a query by taking one of the data on the `name` field that has a few words and?

Table school

```
 id   |         name       |  class
--------------------------------------
 01   | smith, john, billy |   III
 02   | ana, jach, georgre |   IV
```

Controllers

```
//suppose I want to take the data 'smith' on the field name
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $data = $this->models->get_name($name);
    $this->load->view('layout/wrapper', $data);
```

example Query on Models

```
public function get_name($name){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM school 
            WHERE name.name = '".$name."'";

    return $this->db->query($sql)->row_array();
}
```

Comment: U should use array. I think so!

Comment: show your expected result please

Comment: Think you may need to alter the way you are storing your data.  Have a row for each name so `01 - smith - III, 02 - john - III` and so on.  That way you can select the row by name and class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL query finding values in a comma separated string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033047/mysql-query-finding-values-in-a-comma-separated-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FIND_IN_SET()` function to accomplish this task (Here's the CI way to do that instead raw code)

```
public function get_name($name){
    $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('school')->where('FIND_IN_SET(' . $name . ',name) > 0', NULL, FALSE)->get();
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

So now when you will send `smith` it will return first row.

Comment: thanks @Rejoanul Alam my problems have been resolved.

Answer (score -1):

$sql = "SELECT * FROM school WHERE name LIKE ?";

$query = $this->db->query($sql, '%,'.$this->db->escape_like_str($name).',%');

This will return fields from school table, if name = ',name,';

Comment: This is wrong: 1) No protection against SQL injection (`$name` comes straight from `$_POST`) 2) You get results that match partial names (`$name === 'org') 3) Please explain your code...