# How to fetch value from table as per multiple id using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need one help. I need to fetch value from table as per multiple ids which are in comma separated string using MySQL. I am explaining my table and query below.

> db_basic:

```
id      special          name

 1       2,3,4,5          Raj


 2      4,2,5,6           Rahul

 3      3,5,6             Rocky
```

My code is given below.

```
$special=2;
$qry=mysqli_query($connect,"select * from db_basic where special='".$special."'");
```

Here I need where `special=2` is present inside that comma separated string those value will be fetched. I need only proper query. Please help me.

Comment: you should Normalize your DB and save special column in another table, so you can achive what you want with sub query, but in your case look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033047/mysql-query-finding-values-in-a-comma-separated-string

Comment: try to use 'LIKE' operator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL query finding values in a comma separated string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033047/mysql-query-finding-values-in-a-comma-separated-string)

Answer (score 0):

if you current code expeted to return the first and second line of your db, you can use the `LIKE` operator in the query like this :

```
$special=2;
$qry=mysqli_query($connect,"select * from db_basic where special LIKE '%,".$special.",%'");
```

or `LOCATE` like :

```
$special=2;
$qry=mysqli_query($connect,"select * from db_basic where LOCATE(".$special.",special)>0");
```

And `FIND_IN_SET` :  From the docco [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) - "This function does not work properly if the first argument contains a comma (“,”) character".

Comment: @ MacBooc : This `LIKE '%,".$special."',%` is throwing error. Here one , is present with %.

Answer (score 0):

use below query

May be work for u

Use LIKE instead of "="

"select * from db_basic where special LIKE '%".$special."%'"

Answer (score 0):

use FIND_IN_SET function for ex.
select * from db_basic where FIND_IN_SET(2,special)

Answer (score 0):

Try this once,

```
select * from db_basic where FIND_IN_SET($special, special);
```

It should work.