# Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: property mapping has wrong number of columns:

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am developing **Spring Boot + Spring Data JPA + MYSQL** example. In this example, I am getting below error when trying run the example. Film table has column `special_features set('Trailers','Commentaries','Deleted Scenes','Behind the Scenes') DEFAULT NULL,`. In the pojo class, I used like below -

```
@Column(name="special_features")
private Object specialFeatures;
```

[image]

Error:-

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: property mapping has wrong number of columns: com.example.model.Film.specialFeatures type: object
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1694) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1087) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1242) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1230) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at com.example.SpringBootJpaMysqlApplication.main(SpringBootJpaMysqlApplication.java:20) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: property mapping has wrong number of columns: com.example.model.Film.specialFeatures type: object
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:402) ~[spring-orm-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1753) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1690) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: property mapping has wrong number of columns: com.example.model.Film.specialFeatures type: object
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:602) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:461) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate cannot handle the SET datatype out of the box. Even if it could I would be surprised if mapping it to a generic Object would be the way to do it. Hibernate would have no chance to convert that back to a String.

What you need to do is implement an AttributeConverter which converts the String from DB into a fitting Datatype e.g. EnumSet and vice versa. Take a look at the example here: [Mapping EnumSet to mysql Set using JPA 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42136578/mapping-enumset-to-mysql-set-using-jpa-2-1)