# Find Items in a comma separated database column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, database

I am working on searching algorithm for an ecommerce platform. The platform is able to create variations for different products and all the available variations for a products are included in a comma separated column. Here are all the fields.

1. `product_id` - eg 1
2. `variation_combo` - eg 54,35,49 (these are comma separated ids for different variations)
3. `product_name` - eg "Nike branded Tshirt"

Here is what i would like to achieve, something like

- `SELECT product_id FROM table where variation_combo contains 35 AND 54 AND 49`
- `SELECT product_id FROM table where variation_combo contains 35 AND 54`
- `SELECT product_id FROM table where variation_combo contains 49`

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated values. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Having such a `variation_combo` is rather a design flaw. Consider storing the list values in a detail table.

Comment: yeah, i know this. But the software that i am working on has this flaw and changing it now would be really hard. So we have decided to move on with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer this:
[MySQL query finding values in a comma separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033047/mysql-query-finding-values-in-a-comma-separated-string)

```
select product_id from table where find_in_set('35',variation_combo) <> 0   and 
find_in_set('54',variation_combo) <> 0 and find_in_set('49',variation_combo) <> 0
```

Comment: This even provides potential for optimization. Quoting the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set): _"If the first argument is a constant string and the second is a column of type SET, the FIND_IN_SET() function is optimized to use bit arithmetic."_ +1

Comment: Thanks @DmitryEgorov, i really liked your solution but i tested the performance and kapil's query is a bit faster :)

Comment: @omerFarooq: Yes, agree, `find_in_set` definitely suits your case best. Leaving my answer just for the record:)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the LIKE keyword

```
SELECT product_id FROM table where variation_combo LIKE '%35%' AND LIKE '%54%' AND LIKE '%49%'
```

I hope this helps

Comment: What if `variation_combo` has a value of `354`? I doubt it should be selected.

Comment: well i thought of it, but the issue is that if variation_combo contains 
154, 135, 145 then this product would be selected even though it shouldn't have been selected.

Comment: @DmitryEgorov, yup same thought

Comment: When inserting that combos, it would make more sense if you can wrap each combo with a square bracket, like [32], [40] , so it would be easier when searching

Comment: @AlienWhale: and then make extra effort to remove the brackets when representing the actual value? Hardly a good way to go. I'd recommend using `RLIKE`.

Comment: No extra efforts, in the look of things, I think the purpose of that column is to search and suggest, which means he already has the  IDs with him, he won't need to extract again

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend to re-design and move the list values into a detail table.

But if you're absolutely bound to the list in a field design, you may use `RLIKE` to check for a value in the list. If the IDs are just alphanumeric (or more precisely don't contain word boundaries such as `001-01`), any single ID may be matched with the `\bID\b` regex. So your statements would turn to

```
SELECT product_id
    FROM table 
    where variation_combo RLIKE '\\b35\\b'
        AND variation_combo RLIKE '\\b54\\b'
        AND variation_combo RLIKE '\\b49\\b'

SELECT product_id
    FROM table 
    where variation_combo RLIKE '\\b35\\b'
        AND variation_combo RLIKE '\\b54\\b'

SELECT product_id
    FROM table 
    where variation_combo RLIKE '\\b49\\b'
```