# how can we use where condition if data is stored as implode

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3, find-in-set, denormalized

[image]

i want to get all the departments if `location_id` is `3`. that means if location id `3` is used i need to get the department_names of `cardiology` and `hair`

My `controller`

```
public function get_location_departments()
{
   $d = $_POST['location'];
   $data['departments'] = $this->Hospital_model->get_location_departments($d);
   $this->load->view('frontend/ajax_get_departments',$data);
}
```

My `model`

```
public function get_location_departments($d)
{
  $this->db->where_in('location_id',$d);
  $query=$this->db->get('department')->result();
  return $query;
}
```

Comment: Are you only interested in fetching the first digit? if so why not use LIKE?

Comment: [MySQL query finding values in a comma separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5033047/2943403)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use standard spelling & punctuation. PS This is not clear. What is your 1 question?

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*You have to query first to get the `department` and get location_id into an array using `explode`*

Your model `get_location_departments` method should be like this :

```
public function get_location_departments($d)
{
    if (! empty($d))
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('department');
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0 )
        {  
            foreach ($query->result() as $location)
            {
                $location_ids = explode(',',$location->location_id);
                if (in_array($d, $location_ids))
                {
                    $data[] = $location;
                }

            }
        }
    return $data;
    //print_r($data);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

imho the correct answer would be

```
public function get_location_departments($d)
{
    $query = $this->db
        ->where('FIND_IN_SET('.$this->db->escape($d).', location_id)', NULL, false)
        ->get('department')
        ->result();
    return $query;
}
```

> There is a function called `FIND_IN_SET` for that purpose. You can find it in the mysql Documentation under https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set