# Split varchar value used in WHERE clause

Tags: c#, mysql, split, varchar

I am passing a list of string from c# code concatenated to a varchar variable in MySQL, separated by `","`.

I want to split the varchar and use it in my `WHERE` clause like the sample code below:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name IN split(varchar_variable, ",")
```

Do mysql have function as the `split` function that returns an array?
Or if you have some suggestions on how to do it right, thank you in advance.

Comment: In MySQL you can use `FIND_IN_SET` but it would be easier just to put the string directly into the query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL query finding values in a comma separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033047/mysql-query-finding-values-in-a-comma-separated-string)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no such function.

You can do some workaround: if you have ilst of values like

```
value1,value2,value3
```

Then it's enough to look for `,value1,` using `LIKE` operator. n order for this to work you need to pad list with commas:

```
,value1,value2,value3,
```

So your query would become:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE ',' + varchar_variable + ',' LIKE ',' + column_name + ','
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass multiple values inside `WHERE` clause with your `SELECT` statement then you need to modify your `WHERE` clause parameter values like

```
string values = "'\'Albania\',\'Andorra\''";
```

If you debug this code then it will look like,

```
''Albania','Andorra''
```

And in `MySql` editor you can pass same values like,

```
SET @myArray := '\'Albania\',\'Andorra\'';
```

So finally your `SELECT` statement will be,

```
SET @myArray := '\'Albania\',\'Andorra\'';

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT CountryID, CountryName FROM Countries WHERE CountryName IN (', @myArray, ')');

PREPARE statement FROM @sql;
EXECUTE statement;
```

**Output:**

[image]