# Use explode function inside SQL query

Tags: php, sql

I have a database `db` with a column named `type` which is a string.

I want to do an SQL query like this one :

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE explode(",", type) = 'action'
```

Yet it doesn't work because I can't use the explode function in an SQL query. So how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: What is it you're trying to do, check if 'action' is in the comma separated string?

Comment: Is something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033047/mysql-query-finding-values-in-a-comma-separated-string what you are after?

Comment: Any answer will very much depend on your specific RDBMS which you should have [TAGGED](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: Now I guess you know the answer to [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Answer (score 0):

Knowing which db you use can be helpful.

If your database have an explode equivalent with that query you don't match since the explode return a "list" so a list can't match a single value.

Anyway, you don't need to explode the column, just match in it.

Assuming that the column is a string like
"value_1,value_2,value_3,value_4..."

You have 3 possible match to do:

- [1] this will match when the column contains only one value
- [2] this match when value is in first and following position
- [3] this match when the value is in last position

  ```
   SELECT * FROM db WHERE
       "action"=type OR -- [1]
       "action,%" like type OR -- [2]
       "%,action" like type -- [3]
  ```