# Get specific values from comma separated string in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue that I am stuck in,

I have a table called `wpg_original_word` with field tags, which contains comma separated values and what I want to achieve is search for tags which are starting with the letter `'d'`

I have written the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT tags FROM wpg_original_word  WHERE tags LIKE 'd%' ;
```

It returns the whole string like `'Diabetes, Nutrition, Dietician'` , but I want only the `Diabetes, Dietician`.

Any help?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue in SQL Server. You need to split the string, maybe with a stored procedure or a function.

Comment: ok, I am not familiar with that, anyway I will try

Comment: Maybe this post could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835155/mysql-split-comma-seperated-string-into-temp-table

Comment: thanks for your effort, I will look into it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split the string with PHP, use the following code

```
<?php

$string = 'Diabetes, Nutrition, Dietician';
$array = explode(',', $string);
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $part) {
    if (substr(strtolower(trim($part)),0,1) == 'd') {
        array_push($result, trim($part));
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

See it in action here.
http://codepad.org/SVk7FPx9

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I have to change a little bit according to my want

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`in_array()`](http://de3.php.net/in_array) to check for a string in your query and then print it.

Comment: I want to check values starting with a specific letter