# Convert ASCII values to string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where message is a varchar column type.

```
mysql> select * from todel;
+---------+
| message |
+---------+
| 73, 116 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am not able to convert the ASCII values to string.

```
mysql> select char(message) from todel;
+---------------+
| char(message) |
+---------------+
| I             |
+---------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                      |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '73, 116' |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If I use char function directly, then it works as expected:

```
mysql> select char(73, 116);
+---------------+
| char(73, 116) |
+---------------+
| It            |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How do I use the "char" function while selecting varchar data from a table?

Comment: The select version tries to do char('73, 116').

Comment: I think you need to split it and cast to int somehow. Perhaps this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835155/mysql-split-comma-separated-string-into-temp-table

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to separate the two strings and then convert them with `CHAR()`

```
SELECT CHAR(SUBSTRING_INDEX('73, 116', ',', 1)) --I
SELECT CHAR(SUBSTRING_INDEX('73, 116', ',', -1)) --t
```

Comment: There are several such values in a single column cell. As an example I have shown only 2.