# Best approach to fill table from comma separated list in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I implementing stored procedure in mysql for convenient inserting in many-to-many intermediate table. My table have two *column*: `chat_id` and `participant_id`.
I have an api method, that takes chat_id and string with participant_ids separated by commas like `"add_participants?chat_id=1&participant_ids=1,2,3"`
I want stored procedure that can deal with this. Think this is very generic problem in web. But I cant figure out syntax, that will produce me this by parameters `chat_id='1'` and`participant_ids='1,2,3'`

[image]

Comment: As I know group_concat() concatenates multiple values to one string, but I need to insert multiple values from comma separated list.

Comment: Mysql doesn't have a split function.  There are several posts on SO how to do this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835155/mysql-split-comma-separated-string-into-temp-table . . . http://stackoverflow.com/a/19073575/1073631