# MySQL WHERE clause on unnormalized table

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I want to do a `SELECT` query on a table to get product infos. One field of the table is `"productgroup_ids"`. A value looks like this: `"3||4||13"`.

This database was not created by me.

So I wrote a Rest service to get the contents in JSON. Now I want products of a specific group e.g. 3 and 4. I get parameter like this: `"3,4"`

so then the Query should be look like this:

```
"SELECT name, description FROM products WHERE productgroup_ids in (3,4);"
```

But then, I have the problem that only the products only with 3 or 4 are in the result.

Can I parse the value of the field with the query, or do I have to read out all products, split a `"||"`, compare, and if it contains the requested group, add it to an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the small amount of the data (not more than 50 data sets) I selected now all products splitted the field with the groups and checked it with the params.

Now it works. But it's still a bad solution.

Answer (score 0):

i will assume that  `||` are the separators in the database so

first thing:
an example of 3 and 13 is better as this example almost lead me down a wrong solution, for info this one:
(NOT CORRECT SOLUTION)

```
"SELECT name, description FROM products WHERE '||'+productgroup_ids+'||' like '%||'+replace('3,4',',','||')+'||%'
```

but obviously, this would NOT work for 3 and 13

So what now. The obvious answer is that there is no easy way.
The solution is to:
1) split the JSON string into a temporary table
2) do a select with a join

To split the string into temp table take a look at this:
[MySQL Split Comma Separated String Into Temp Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835155/mysql-split-comma-separated-string-into-temp-table)

Lets assume the temp. table is called TempJSONCategory has only one column called category.
then do a select like this:

```
SELECT name, description 
  FROM products 
 WHERE products_primary_key in
       (select products_primary_key 
          from products
          join TempJSONCategory 
            on '||'+products.productgroup_ids+'||' like '%||'+TempJSONCategory.category+'||%')
```

Tadaaa. Thats it. Yes, its not really pretty, but reasonably fast. But thats the price for having a bad DB design :-/

Edit: Had to edit, select was a bit wrong:

Comment: Yeah the problem with 3 and 13 and so on was the reason i asked this question. :D Your second suggestion should be the right thing, but "so much" work for actually nothing. And I cant normalize the tables because somebody else manage the CMS which is using this database...