# MySQL - How to extract all values between delimiters

Tags: mysql

I have a table created by a scheduler application that contains two columns, `ID` and `WEEK` in the form of `["1","2","5","10","20","52"]`. 
I would like to extract and normalize the ID and WEEK columns to be able to plot a timeline. Unfortunately I wouldn't even know where to start.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Split Comma Separated String Into Temp Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835155/mysql-split-comma-separated-string-into-temp-table)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+


SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX (SUBSTRING_INDEX('1,2,5,10,20,52',',',i+1),',',-1)+0 x FROM ints;
+----+
| x  |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  5 |
| 10 |
| 20 |
| 52 |
+----+
```

Comment: I do have more than one row. In fact I need to create temp tables out of any given row in that schedule table to be used in some views elsewhere. I do at temp table creation only know the scheduler id and not what is in the weeks column. As a complication I'd have to process any request in ONE select statement, not 1+n