# MySQL trigger not updating multiple rows when WHERE IN used

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have two tables:

```
table1
------
id, status

table2
------
id,items
```

`status` in `table1` can be one of "Paid", "Pending", "Requested".

`items` in `table2` contains comma separated `id` of `table1`.

ie.

```
table1
------
1 | Requested
2 | Requested
3 | Pending

table2 
------
1 | 1,2
```

I wanted to update `status` of `table1` from "Requested" to "Paid" whenever any item added into field `items` of `table2`.

Also I wanted to reset `status` to "Requested" if item is removed from table2 `items` field on update.

So created 3 triggers:

1) After INSERT:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER `Update status` AFTER INSERT ON `table2`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      UPDATE table1 
      SET status = 'Paid' 
      WHERE id IN (NEW.items);
 END
```

2) Before UPDATE:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Reset on update` 
BEFORE UPDATE ON `table2`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE table1 SET status = 'Requested' WHERE 
    id IN (OLD.items)
END
```

3) After UPDATE:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `New status on update` AFTER UPDATE ON `table2`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE table1 SET status = 'Paid' WHERE id IN (NEW.items);
END
```

The problem is triggers are updating only one row(1st of comma separated `id`) of table1 in of the above all triggers.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It is "bad practice" to put multiple values in a single column.  It is better to make another table for the many:many mapping you have.

Comment: I have already moved my data into new table yesterday. Because its was getting hectic to manage all data in one table. Thank you Rick.

Answer (score 1):

If `NEW.items` is `1,2,3,4,5` the statement `UPDATE table1 SET status = 'Paid' WHERE id IN (NEW.items);` actually means:

```
UPDATE table1 SET status = 'Paid' WHERE id IN ('1,2,3,4,5');
```

instead of:

```
UPDATE table1 SET status = 'Paid' WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5);
```

`'1,2,3,4,5'` then gets cast to an integer and becomes `1`.

Comment: Any suggestion to archive `(1,2,3,4,5)` instead of ('1,2,3,4,5')?

Comment: Solved using answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835155/mysql-split-comma-separated-string-into-temp-table