# SQL: Inserting all possible pairs from two parameter lists

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in a MySQL database which relates items and tags, with columns `item_id, tag_id`. I need to write a query which receives a list of items and a list of tags and applies each tag to each item.

My current implementation looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO item_tag (item_id, tag_id) 
  (SELECT tag.tag_id, item.item_id FROM tag, item
  WHERE tag.tag_id in (:tags) 
   AND  item.item_id in (:items))
```

And this works but it's hacky and inneficient, I'm querying the `tag` and `item` tables to fetch values I already have in the parameters (and I already know at this point those are valid ids, so I don't really need to check for existence).

Is there a cleaner way to do this? For example I think of something like (psuedo code):

```
SELECT * FROM all_values_in_a_column(:tags) 
JOIN all_values_in_a_column(:items)
```

Comment: Essentially an implied `CROSS JOIN`?

Comment: Yes, a cross join, but over the values in the parameters

Comment: So you have two lists and you want the combinations of them? Any reason you don't just do it in whichever scripting language you're using?

Comment: I could do it at application level too, but then I would end up sending a really long query to the DBMS. I'll probably go with that option if there is no easy way to implement it in SQL.

Comment: MySQL doesn't seem to have an easy way of doing this... here might be a good start, but probably not worth the overhead, you'd need to benchmark this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835155/mysql-split-comma-separated-string-into-temp-table

Comment: I finally solved it at application level. Thanks for the help anyway. I'll leave the question open in case someone finds a way to do this in SQL.