# Matching records from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two Tables: ads_info and ads.

I want to match records from two tables.

SQL Schema for ads:

```
| id |                 title |
|----|-----------------------|
|  1 | This Dog is very nice |
```

SQL Schema for ads_info:

```
| id |                     infotext |       tag |
|----|------------------------------|-----------|
|  1 | Dogs can eat a lot of things | dog, pets |
```

I want to check if the title of the Ads with id 1 has tags in ads_info. I have tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM `ads` where id = '1' UNION
SELECT * FROM `ads_info` where tag like '%ads.title%'
```

HERE IS SQL FIDDLE: [LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ceb2c9/4)

Comment: Please show the results you want.  Why are you storing tags in a comma-delimited list?  That is not the right way to store data in SQL databases.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a simple `join`?

```
select a.*, ai.tag,
       (tag like concat('%', ads.title, '%')) as flag
from ads a join
     ads_info ai
     on ai.id = a.id;
```

The `flag` is, of course, false.  It is rather hard to see situations where it would evaluate to true as you have expressed the logic.

Comment: I have tried something like this: `select * from ads a
left join ads_info b on b.tag like ('%'+a.title+'%') where a.id='1'`

Comment: @Gordon Linoff it is `('%', a.title, '%')` and not `('%', ads.title, '%')`

Comment: So just add where part to this Gordon's code. Like: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ceb2c9/20 ?

Comment: Have tried it and it doesn't do what I want. It doesnt search for dog

Comment: If you change Dog it show it again: Look http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ddb915/1

Comment: It must be `select * from ads a
inner join ads_info b on a.title like concat('%', b.tag, '%') where a.id='1'` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do it this way : [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=77f9ba1df39f3fb1d9dea7a4bbafb4ce) I am sure there are better ways and even this example can be better executed :) But it will maybe help...

First you create function for split and procedure for inserting those values in table(I have used here a answer from here [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835155/mysql-split-comma-separated-string-into-temp-table) and corrected some small errors):

**FUNCTION**

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

**PROCEDURE**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ABC(in fullstr VARCHAR(255))

BEGIN

DECLARE a int default 0;
DECLARE str VARCHAR(255);

      simple_loop: LOOP
         SET a=a+1;
         SET str=SPLIT_STR(fullstr,",",a);
         IF str='' THEN
            LEAVE simple_loop;
         END IF;

         insert into my_temp_table values (str);
      END LOOP simple_loop;
END;
```

I have created a table for this values:

```
create table my_temp_table (temp_columns varchar(100));
```

Called the procedure:

```
 call ABC((select tag from ads_info));
```

And then you can use this:

```
Select * from ads B where exists
(select * from my_temp_table where 
find_in_set(UPPER(trim(temp_columns)), replace(UPPER(B.TITLE), ' ', ',')) > 0 );
```

Or this:

```
SELECT * FROM ads, my_temp_table
WHERE find_in_set(UPPER(trim(temp_columns)), replace(UPPER(ads.TITLE), ' ', ',')) > 0 ;
```