# SQL: With two inner joins and concat

Tags: mysql, sql

I use this query to get an Ads Info by title. My SQL Code:

This SQL Code work but it search only for title.

```
select a.title, b.type from ads a
inner join ads_infos b on a.title like concat('%', b.type, '%')
where a.id='1'
```

I want to use Inner Join with Concat for title and description.

```
select a.title, b.type from ads a
inner join ads_infos b on a.title like concat('%', b.type, '%')
inner join ads_infos b on a.description like concat('%', b.type, '%')
where a.id='1'
```

but this doesnt work.

SQL FIDDLE: [Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2356f6/1)

Comment: So you have repeated the question and used an answer from someone who helped you in your new question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58671327/matching-records-from-two-tables

Comment: try to use a different alias for the second join of `ads_infos`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In this case if you need  two conditions on the same table, you should use `AND`   if you need  both

```
select a.title
, b.type 
from ads a
inner join ads_infos b on a.title like concat('%', b.type, '%')
   AND a.description like concat('%', b.type, '%')
 where a.id='1'
```

or

`OR`  if you need  one of the two

```
select a.title
, b.type 
from ads a
inner join ads_infos b on a.title like concat('%', b.type, '%')
  OR a.description like concat('%', b.type, '%')
 where a.id='1'
```

Comment: It doesnt work?

Comment: near 'on a.description like concat('%', b.type, '%') where a.id='1'' at line 5

Comment: answer  updated ..  ans removed   ..  wrong ON

Comment: Thank YOU <3 Do you know how to make more types ? I want to seperate it.

Comment: @DrohnenMeister  what do you mean  ..  your comment is not clear to me ..  eventually post a proper question and comment me the link