# How To Join Explode Data in Laravel

Tags: jquery, mysql, laravel

I am working on a ride-sharing app where currently available Cars are showing based on the status with below query in `Laravel`

```
 $cars = CarType::select('id')->where('status','Active')->get();
```

I need to implement a user hiring preference where user can save which service he wants to hire. For this, I am planning to save user-preferred `carid's` as a comma-separated value in the `users` table like below

[image]

After then I am wanting to show car's based on preferences for each user like

```
select c.id from car_type c
INNER JOIN
users u 
on c.id in **car id's saved in ride_preferences column in users table**
and c.status='Active'
where('id', $user_details->id)->first();// my current laravel query to check current user
```

How can I write above query in `Laravel`?

Comment: In $user_details variable you have user object?

Comment: $user_check = User::where('id', $user_details->id)->first();

Comment: tbh, having the preferred `carId` in comma-separated column is not a great idea for proper relational database. but given you kind of stuck, i could only offer [this approach that uses a rather complicated stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11835246/4648586). you can change the pipe (`|`) into comma, and do trim the output first. if you want to keep the logic stays in the app, doing a loop is your best bet (but it hit your performance worse). curious question, is the table structure fixed or we have chance to set things straight?

Comment: I think that choice of your Database (Mysql) is not correct for ride sharing app, consider the app design and traffic you would receive after 100-150 simultaneous connections. There are other open source real time DB like RethinkDB, just my 2 cents

Comment: @BlackXero The company behind RethinkDB is shutting down as they announce it [RethinkDB](https://rethinkdb.com/blog/rethinkdb-shutdown/).

Comment: This is a prime example of why it's important to normalize your database tables

Comment: @MahmoudMostafa I am aware of that fact but I just listed it as an example.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this in a relational database, there is a way better approach. Create a relational structure.

```
ride_preferences
int id
int user_id
int car_id
```

User model

```
public function ridePreferences()
{
    return $this->hasMany(RidePreferences::class);
}
```

RidePreference model

```
public function car()
{
    $this->belongsTo(Car::class);
}
```

The query then.

```
$carsPreferred = User::with('ridePreferences.car')->first()->ridePreferences->map->car;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `DB:raw`:

```
$results = DB::select( DB::raw("select c.id from car_type c
INNER JOIN
users u 
on c.id in **car id's saved in ride_preferences column in users table**
and c.status='Active' where `id`=" . $user_details->id . ") );
```

Or:

```
$results = DB::select( DB::raw("select c.id from car_type c
INNER JOIN
users u 
on c.id in **car id's saved in ride_preferences column in users table**
and c.status='Active' where `id`=:id"), array(
   'id' => $id,
 )));
```

Or:

```
$results = DB::select( DB::raw("select c.id from car_type c
INNER JOIN
users u 
on c.id in **car id's saved in ride_preferences column in users table**
and c.status='Active'"))->where('id', $id);
```

And don't forget to add `$results->get();`

Comment: `DB::select(...)` which is `DB::connection()->select(...)` returns an array