# sql split one column into multiple columns

Tags: python, sql, split, data-cleaning

I am trying to split the string from a column into multiple columns using Python. My data base is in SQL Server The strings have Persian characters including numbers, like:

\ارزگان\جلد 10 اصل اساس سال 1353 مرکز(ترینکوت) ولایت ارزگان\138.pdf

How should I split the words in to separate columns in my SQL database by using Python jupyther.

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use? SQL Server | MySQL | Oracle | ... ? (E.G. [for MySQL : Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11835155/4519059))

Comment: Can you please explain what ultimately you are going to achieve by putting each word in separate column? If you may explain it further then we might come up with some alternative solutions.

Comment: I am using SQL Server, and try to make the data searchable in search engine and of course countable.