# What is the maximum length of string for CONCAT in MySQL (Aurora-MySql)?

Tags: mysql, concatenation, amazon-aurora

I currently have an MySQL (Aurora MySQL based on MySQL 5.7.x) `PROCEDURE` that takes a stringified list of ids as `TEXT` and uses a `CONCAT` function to create a prepared statement for execution.

While the procedure works most of the time, I am getting truncation errors on a few calls to it (likely that have a lot of IDs). The error message is essentially:

> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation   Data truncation: Data too long for column 'stuffIds' at row 1

My initial thought was that we had selected too small of a type for the `PROCEDURE` param `stuffIds`, but when I checked, I discovered it's type is `TEXT`. It seems REALLY unlikely that our service is maxing out that type, <strike>which to my knowledge is limited at 2^31 chars (or 2GB of data)</strike>. We just don't have enough IDs in any list to hit that limit.

My next thought was that maybe it's related to the `CONCAT` function that we're using to create the prepared statement? But while I've seen lots of issues & answers around `GROUP_CONCAT` and its max length (and the related configs), I have not been able to locate any info on the max length of string supported by MySQL's `CONCAT` function.

The only thing left I could think of was that maybe it's related specifically to AWS Aurora's implementation of MySQL? I think Aurora is supposed to be pretty close to vanilla MySQL, but maybe this is an edge case?

The `PROCEDURE` itself (the names have been changed to protect the innocent) raising this error looks like:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetThingsByStuffIds(stuffIds TEXT)

BEGIN

SET @stmt = CONCAT('SELECT ThingId FROM ThingTable WHERE StuffId IN (', stuffIds, ')');

PREPARE insert_stm FROM @stmt;
EXECUTE insert_stm;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE insert_stm;


END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Any insights are appreciated. Thanks!

---

**UPDATE/NOTE/WARNING!**

As @Schwern pointed out, I had my MySQL `TEXT` type info wrong!

> which to my knowledge is limited at 2^31 chars (or 2GB of data)

That part of my question was very incorrect! Unlike PostgreSQL, as @Schwern states below, MySQL has three sized variants of `TEXT` - `TEXT` (65,535 chars), `MEDIUMTEXT` (16,777,215 chars), `LONGTEXT` (4,294,967,295 chars). I misunderstood the length limits of `TEXT`, hence why my call was exceeding the limits. The full info on these types in [MySQL is here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-type-syntax.html). Adding this note so my misinformation in the question doesn't mislead anyone!

Comment: Is the column named `stuffId` or `stuffIds`? The error message says the column is `stuffIds`, but your query uses `stuffId`.

Comment: I know you changed names, but you need to make it clear whether the error message is referring to the table column or the procedure parameter.

Comment: BTW, instead of creating a prepared statement, you could just use the `FIND_IN_SET()` function.

Comment: @Barmar `StuffID` is the column name, `stuffIds` is the param string list of IDs I'm using in the `IN` clause. `FIND_IN_SET()` is a good idea sometimes for simplicity, but unfortunately it doesn't work well for me because I've found that it disregards indexes and performance is essential in my case. `IN` is well optimized and will leverage indexes. Thanks for the suggestions though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`text`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings) cannot be larger than 2^16 *bytes* or 65,535. Depending on the character set, characters can take up multiple bytes, but if it's simple UTF-8 it's probably one byte per character.

You could use `mediumtext` (2^24 bytes) or `longtext` (2^32 bytes), but really your table needs to be redesigned. ***Storing lists as comma separated strings is extremely inefficient, complex, and error prone***. Instead, use a [many-to-many join table](https://ozenero.com/sql-tutorial-mysql-many-to-many-relationship).

```
create thing_stuff (
  thing_id int not null references thing(id),
  stuff_id int not null references stuff(id)
);

-- Thing 1 has Stuff 2 and 5.
insert into thing_stuff (thing_id, stuff_id) values
  (1, 2), (1, 5);

-- Get all the Stuff associated with Thing 1.
select stuff.*
from stuff s
join thing_stuff ts on ts.stuff_id = s.id
where thing_id = 1;

-- Thing 1 no longer has Stuff 5.
delete from thing_stuff
where thing_id = 1 and stuff_id = 5;
```

Comment: Thanks, @Schwern. You're absolutely right about `MEDIUMTEXT` & `LONGTEXT`. I somehow lived life never realizing those existed in MySQL - likely because I came from a PostgreSQL world prior (which lumps them as `TEXT`). In light of that, we were likely hitting the 65.5k limit (our id's are currently up to 10 digits length), so it all makes sense now.

Comment: And good tip, but no worries, we don't use comma separated strings in our tables. Those are only to build the queries in our stored procedures (because MySQL doesn't have a list-type, so we can't call a `PROCEDURE` with a List of `BIGINT`). `StuffId` on the `ThingTable` is a foreign key to `StuffTable` that we're querying via the list `IN` clause.

Comment: @cjn Consider putting the ids into a temp table and passing in the name of the table. Or if you can replace the need for a procedure with a view.

Answer (score 1):

You will encounter a Problem as the IN Clause has a limit to the number of values it can hold and it is directly linked the max_[allowed_packet size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet)

A better Solution is to split the id string and add it to a temporary table and join both, with big numbers of elements this is also faster

The split function i lend form https://stackoverflow.com/a/11835246/5193536

> ```
> CREATE TABLE ThingTable(StuffId int,ThingId int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO ThingTable VALUES (1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(5,5)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
>   x VARCHAR(255),
>   delim VARCHAR(12),
>   pos INT
> )
> RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
> RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
>        LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
>        delim, '');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE GetThingsByStuffIds(stuffIds TEXT)
>
> BEGIN
>       DECLARE a INT Default 0 ;
>       DECLARE str TEXT;
>       DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS my_temp_table;
>       CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_temp_table(aint int);
>       simple_loop: LOOP
>          SET a=a+1;
>          SET str=SPLIT_STR(stuffIds,",",a);
>          IF str='' THEN
>             LEAVE simple_loop;
>          END IF;
>          #Do Inserts into temp table here with str going into the row
>          insert into my_temp_table values (str);
>    END LOOP simple_loop;
>
> SELECT ThingId FROM ThingTable t1 INNER JOIN  my_temp_table t2 ON t1.StuffId = t2.aint;
>
>
>
> END
> ```

> ```
> CALL GetThingsByStuffIds('1,2,3,4,5,6')
> ```
>
> ```
> | ThingId |
> | ------: |
> |       1 |
> |       2 |
> |       3 |
> |       5 |
>
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ddc3a048b0b5e8ac0e13cb6b35683e69)*

Comment: Good insight! I had some wrong thinking around type info in MySQL, so that turned out to be the issue this time. BUT, I was not aware of this limitation in  the `IN` clause, so if that didn't bite us now, it likely could later. Thanks for the valuable insight, @nbk!