# How to make the column wildcard based on the entry?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

As you know, if you use `.. where col_name like "%word%"`, then it will be searching as wildcard. Ok, all is file. Now I want exactly the vice versa. I mean, I want to make the column wildcard based on the entry.

Please take a look at this:

```
// tb_name
+--------------+
|   col_name   |
+--------------+
| Ali          |
| Martin       |
| John         |
+--------------+
```

I want to match the third row by this value: `John Foo`. Or match the first row by this entry: `Mr Ali`. So conceptically I want something like this: `.. where %col_name% like "word"`. How can I do that in MySQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stich the wildcards `%` to the col_name.

Then you can like John Foo.

```
select *
from tb_name 
where 'John Foo' like concat('%',col_name,'%')
```

But if col_name is indexed, then using `IN` will be faster.
Because `concat('%',col_name,'%')` isn't [sargable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

```
select *
from tb_name 
where col_name IN ('John','Foo')
```

Or the more complicated way, by getting the parts from the name string.

```
select t.*
from tb_name t
cross join (select 'John Foo Bar' name) names
where t.col_name IN (
           substring_index(name,' ',1), 
           substring_index(substring_index(name,' ', 2),' ',-1), 
           substring_index(substring_index(name,' ', 3),' ',-1)
          )
```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8ca64616809619fb534b9e56ecf2bdab)*

Comment: Is any approach to take words apart based on the space using MySQL ?

Comment: You mean something like [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) in MS Sql Server that splits a character seperated string to rows? Then no, by my knowledge, MySql doesn't have something like that.  And a MySql function can't return a table, only procedures can.  But some complicated tricks could work. F. e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45761467/4003419)

Comment: Well, I need to make `IN ('John','Foo')` according to "John Foo" string somehow to take advantage of indexes *(as you mentioned)*

Comment: See addition. It assumes there's not more than 3 parts to a name though.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use [LOCATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate).

SELECT *
FROM tb_name
WHERE LOCATE(name, 'John Foo') > 0