# filter ids by comma separated input ids MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

My procedure takes input of CSV of Ids

```
select Value from (
select value from string_split('1,2,3',',')) as t 
where t.value not in (select id from demotable)
```

The above solution is for SQL server. I want to do the same with MYSQL.

Do we have any function that works similar to string_split function in MYSQL?

And the solution should not loop through every input Id.

Comment: The CSV values `1,2,3` really belong inside a proper table.  Any reason why you can't do that?

Comment: My procedure gets input of CSV of Ids

Comment: [split_string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835155/mysql-split-comma-separated-string-into-temp-table)

Comment: [split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950466/how-to-split-the-name-string-in-mysql)