MySQL Split String of unknown length
I have a string that contains a path.
Example:
Sample Set/::/itemtypes/::/Baselines
I am trying to split this into the following sequence
1 Sample Set
2 itemtypes
3 Baselines

I have tried many ways, like:
WITH RECURSIVE ProductCTE AS (
    SELECT 
        b.fieldvalue AS FIELDVALUE,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(b.fieldvalue, '/::/', 1) AS ProductName,
        1 AS StartIndex
    FROM baselineversionfield b 
    where b.documentfieldid = 458
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        FIELDVALUE,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(FIELDVALUE, '/::/', StartIndex + 1), '/::/', -1) AS ProductName,
        StartIndex + 1 AS StartIndex
    FROM 
        ProductCTE
    WHERE 
        StartIndex < LENGTH(FIELDVALUE) - LENGTH(REPLACE(FIELDVALUE, '/::/', '')) + 1
)
SELECT 
   *
FROM 
    ProductCTE;

The above only gets me the last string in the full string.  I need all of them.  How can I get this working?

literally, you want to convert a string into a table, and it is a very tricky thing in MySQL - see possible solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835155/mysql-split-comma-separated-string-into-temp-table

I looked at those already and they do not do what I am after
