# MySQL explode array of values to use to ORDER the result by

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have to store a different number of values in a column called, date_of, for the date of an event. There can be multiple dates that it takes place, for instance Oct 1st, 2nd, and 6th. And I need to store that in that column as three different dates. Now I do this like this:

```
1350619200, 1350705600, 1350792000
```

So what I want to be able to do is order the mysql result by the date(s). The first date should be the one that it gets ordered by, however if there are multiple dates as shown above, if the date is pass then it should go to the second date, then third date etc.

I'm not sure how to get started with this, my main priority is to just order the results by the first date in the array, the other part of my question isn't as important.

Comment: Check out this link... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096679/can-mysql-split-a-column

Comment: Couldn't you make a new table which stores the dates, one date per data row and join with your main table? It would be normalized so.

Comment: Well, normally I would do something like that and not have an array of dates or any information - I am highly against doing things that way - however in this circumstance it is just for a simple website that won't be used much, (It's really just a CMS for a single user to manage their small business).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you order by the first field, which is always set, then you can try extracting the field:

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(date_of, ',', 1);
```

Actually, you could order by `date_of`, since lexicographic order is maintained. You'd be in trouble if you wanted to order by the *last* subfield, but since you want the first...

Now "if the first element of the date is past" is a bit tricky.

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(date_of, ',', 1) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
    THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(date_of, ',', 1)
    ELSE ... END
```

could be a start, but then if there is *no* second subfield? If we iterate SUBSTRING_INDEX, we get again the first field.

You would have to iterate the `CASE` itself. *Shudder*

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(date_of, ',', 1) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
    THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(date_of, ',', 1)
    ELSE
        CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(date_of, ',', 2),',',-1) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
        THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(date_of, ',', 2),',',-1)
        ELSE
            CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(date_of, ',', 3),',',-1) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
            THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(date_of, ',', 3),',',-1)
            ELSE 999999999
            END
        END
    END
```

I can see there's no great performances to be had from this structure. I would **strongly** advise for having the three dates in three different columns, or the model reengineered to have dates in a separate table.

Comment: Well, I gave some thoughts about the rest. Not very promising, I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok, well thank you for the additional code, I may give that a go, but I also may decide just not to bother as well. I'll quote what I said a minute ago to someone's response, "  
Well, normally I would do something like that and not have an array of dates or any information - I am highly against doing things that way - however in this circumstance it is just for a simple website that won't be used much, (It's really just a CMS for a single user to manage their small business)."  

However, would there be a simple way to get the last date from the array, similarly to how you get the first row

Comment: If not, I could always flip the array around when I insert it to the database so the "last" date is always the first result, I guess that may be the most plausible solution in this case.

Comment: Yes, just use SUBSTRING_INDEX(date_of,',',-1) and it will get you the last element. Or the first if you have only one.

Answer (score 1):

If you store it as a string (`VARCHAR`) then you can just do a `ORDER BY` on the query. MySQL will do a lexographic sort on the string. If you are storing unix timestamps (which you appear to be), then this will work until 20th November 2286 5:46:40 PM UTC.

It works because all the timestamps are likely to be the same length, 10 digits. You just have to make sure that keep the format of the list consistent. I'd go for `<number>,<number,...` no spaces.

Comment: Ok thanks, I suppose this would be fine to do, but I'm just going to use the proper way just to be safe, thanks though!