# Split comma separated value from table column into rows using mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I found the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096679/can-mysql-split-a-column) which has the column with 3 values seperated by commas. I will have more than 3 values seperated by commas . For example,

```
ID    CITY_ID
--------------
1     12,18,16,17,35
2     12,16
....
--------------
```

Is it possible to split string city_id and make it into rows using mysql query like below

```
  ID   CITY_ID
  -------------
   1    12
   1    18
   1    16
    ....
   2    16
    ....
  --------------
```

If yes, Kindly give some advice ....

Comment: You can write a procedure to do it, but it's pretty messy.  You may as well implement it in PHP by looping over each record.

Comment: @eggyal Thanks. I could do that But want to know whether it is possible in mysql....

Comment: It can be done in mysql but too as eggyal said, its messy. Is php an option?

Comment: @itachi Thanks,yes i am doing with php

Comment: So , you have a solution with PHP and can close this question or still need help with the php script?

Comment: Please mark the answer below as the correct answer. Others need to be able to find it, as many ask and nothing comes close to being this simple and working this well.

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
  SELECT ID,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.CITY_ID, ',', n.n), ',', -1) value
  FROM Table1 t CROSS JOIN 
  (
   SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
     FROM 
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
    ORDER BY n 
   ) n
 WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.CITY_ID) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.CITY_ID, ',', '')))
 ORDER BY ID,value
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ca19c/1)**

Output:

---

```
ID  VALUE
1   12
1   16
1   17
1   18
1   35
2   12
2   16
```

Comment: This works surprisingly well! I need to debug a bit to see if it is limited to 9 entries or not, but it looks like it will be fine for my purposes.

Comment: This is such a brilliant piece of SQL. Many people are looking for this in other threads but haven't found it. I wish  I could give you more up votes.

Comment: BTW - It works for up to 100 comma separated values, not just 9. It could easily be extended to more if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Reference: https://gist.github.com/duanehutchins/c6000b367b3032b0b495c46b3bc370c8

Functions:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `SET_COUNT`;
        
CREATE FUNCTION `SET_COUNT`($strlist MEDIUMBLOB) RETURNS SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED
NO SQL
DETERMINISTIC
RETURN 1+CHAR_LENGTH($strlist)-CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE($strlist,',',''));
              
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `SET_EXTRACT`;
             
CREATE FUNCTION `SET_EXTRACT`($i SMALLINT UNSIGNED, $strlist MEDIUMBLOB) RETURNS VARBINARY(255)
NO SQL
DETERMINISTIC
RETURN NULLIF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(0b0, ',', $strlist, ',', 0b0), ',', $i+1.5*(SIGN($i+0.5)+1)-1), ',', -SIGN($i+0.5)),0b0);
```

use:

```
  SELECT SET_EXTRACT(n.digit, 'a,b,c,d,f,g')AS split_value FROM  (SELECT 0 digit 
  UNION ALL SELECT 1 
  UNION ALL SELECT 2 
  UNION ALL SELECT 3  
  UNION ALL SELECT 4 
  UNION ALL SELECT 5 
  UNION ALL SELECT 6
  UNION ALL SELECT 7
  UNION ALL SELECT 8
  UNION ALL SELECT 9
  UNION ALL SELECT 10) AS  n WHERE n.digit < set_count('a,b,c,d,f,g')
```