# How to split comma separated values to new rows?

Tags: mysql

i have table in the following format

```
**id   mobile  landline**
x1   2,3,4   17,18
x2   4,5,6
x3   7,8,9   19
```

trying to insert the data in a table in the following table.

```
**id  mobile  landline**
x1  2       17
x1  3       18
x1  4
```

Please help.

Comment: Always 3 numbers? What are their range?

Comment: there can be any range it is just an example.

Comment: To the best of my recollection, there is no `split` function in MySQL. You may wish to develop one of your own (or google; I recall seeing many examples, though no recollection of  MySQL specific).

Comment: This isn't going to be a one-step operation. Do you have to have an ongoing process for new data, or is this a one-time operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the end table structure negotiable? Might I propose:

```
id  type    value
x1  mobile  2
x1  mobile  3
x1  mobile  4
x1  landline  17
x1  landline  18
```

or if you have to go with columns for landline and mobile:

```
id  mobile  landline**
x1  2       <null>
x1  3       <null>
x1  4       <null>
x1  <null>  17       
x1  <null>  18
```

Otherwise it appears that landline 17 is associated with mobile 2, which isn't implied in the source table.

Once you've decided that, check out [Split comma separated value from table column into rows using mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872277/split-comma-separated-value-from-table-column-into-rows-using-mysql?rq=1) and see if you can apply that solution.