# Picklist data sorting in MySQL

Tags: mysql, picklist

I have two columns *(Please check the image)* based on which I want to create a third column stating that they are a 'match'

| col 1 | col 2 | Match column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MA;NY | NY | Match |
| MA;NY | FL | Un-match |
| KS | AR;KY;LA;MS | Un-Match |
| KY | AR;KY;LA;MS | Match |

However, both the columns are off a 'picklist' data type and I am not sure how to perform that in mysql.

**P.S Both the columns have multiple entries with a delimiter as ';', so the logic go true in both cases. col 1 to col 2 *and* col 2 to col 1**

I tried using
`SELECT col 2 IN (SELECT col 1 from table 1) FROM table 2` however, it only works on some records (strange)

Comment: Please post data as text instead of an image.

Comment: Can there be lists on both sides?  If not then you can use `replace()` to change `;` to `,` then to get a strlist, then use `find_in_set(col1, replace(col2, ';', ','))` and the same thing with col1 and col2 switched.

Comment: please read up on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @AllanWind I have updated the post with text

Comment: @Swas thanks, but you lost rows so data no longer match the "In the above example rows 2,3,5,8 ..."

Comment: @AllanWind ya, I just deleted them and appended them in the 3rd column

Comment: If you have lists on both col1 and col2, then you probably need to expand a given row into n rows.   There are existing questions covering.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872277/split-comma-separated-value-from-table-column-into-rows-using-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of values in *either* (but not both) col1 or col2 then you can do:

```
select
  col1,
  col2,
  find_in_set(col1, replace(col2, ';', ',')) or
  find_in_set(col2, replace(col1, ';', ','))
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you for the code Allan. Yes, they are a list of values. I was trying the exact solution that you provided above, in the meantime. I am just running the code to see the results.

Comment: Hi Allan, I am trying to create a case statement based on the above solution which mentions the 'match' and 'unmatched'. I would surely accept it once its done