# Splitting a field into two fields in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a field that contains the fullname of a user (Fullname). I'd need to split it into two other fields FirstName and LastName.
Ideally with one query I'd like to be able to populate the FirstName and LastName columns from the value contained in the Fullname.
Thanks.

Comment: This should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096679/can-mysql-split-a-column

Comment: @Andrea Nagar: how you are storing the firstname and lastname as fullname, what is the separator you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try (if firstname and lastname are sepparated by a whitespace):

```
update table_name
   set FirstName=substr(FullName,1,locate(' ',FullName)),
       LastName=substr(FullName,locate(' ',FullName)+1);
```

Comment: Or us [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index).