# Need help building hash tag trending query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, hashtag, trending

I'm trying to build a query that measures "trending" hash tags like tweets. I have a table tweets and a column message (varchar)

Basically I just want to group the messages by a hash tag but it breaks down if there is more than 1 hash tag in the message field, heres what I have so far

```
SELECT count(message) as count, `message` FROM `tweets` WHERE `message` RLIKE '^#[[:alnum:]]' GROUP BY `tweets`.`message` ORDER BY `count` DESC
```

which will output the following rows

```
"4","#sushi"
"3","#coffee"
"3","#wine"
"1","#coffee #park"
"1","#drinking"
"1","#steak"
"1","#pizza"
"1","#pasta"
"1","#food"
```

The fourth row is the problem where I would want both hash tags totaled on their own, not sure if I can achieve this with just mysql.

Comment: Can there be more than two hash tags - is it unlimited?

Comment: You are going to have to split the column [other post that might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096679/can-mysql-split-a-column)

Comment: yes you can achieve this by referencing your table to its own. First you have to get the ``count`` and ``message``. Then try to reference fetch the 3rd column using the same query. Anyway, what is the 3rd column?

Comment: The values are stored as a single value, How can they be differentiated as different hash tags? This design will make things unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 0):

Your column is `message` but you want to group by hashtags.  From a database design POV, your table isn't in 1NF because `message` actually holds a *repeating group* of hash tags.  You won't be able to use the power of SQL on your table until that's corrected.

What you need is another table `hashtags` that has one row for every tag in every message. Once you have that, the query practically writes itself.